# iPhone UIImagePickerController video player get selected video location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an application where I have used an UIImagePickerController to select a video. I am using XCode 3.2.5. I have used the following code

```
UIImagePickerController *picker;
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;  
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

This is allowing me to view only the videos that I have in the PhotoLibrary. But when I select a video, it opens in a video player. There the options are to choose the video for compression or to go back to the previous view. When I press on the compress button, the application hangs up on the simulator, but on the device, the video gets compressed and the UIImagePickerController gets dismissed.

I wanted to actually pass the location of this video as soon as the user selects it from the PhotoLibrary, but it opens automatically in the video player. Is there any delegate method which can be called when the user selects a video from the Photo Library using the UIImagePickerController. I have tried all the delegate methods of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, but they are only executed if we select an image, and not a video. Further, is it possible to add a functionality to the player which plays the video inside the UIImagePickerController. Is there any work around solution. Please Help.

Comment: What did mean by " plays the video inside the UIImagePickerController " ????

Answer (score 1):

1). 
**I wanted to actually pass the location of this video as soon as the user selects it from the PhotoLibrary** : - 
 For this you can use `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method like :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   NSURL *selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}
```

Comment: but the problem is, The delegate method - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info is not getting called when I select a video, but it works for images. Please help.